# Where specifically do UIImageWriteToSavePhotosAlbum or UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum save their data?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, video, camera, photo

Simple question I think and I'll be trying ot myself to see... When people talk about using `UIImageWriteToSavePhotosAlbum` or `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` is the "saved photos album" the "Camera Roll" or the "Photo Library" (or something else either than these two) that I see in the Photo Albums application? I don't think the doc makes it super-explicit as to which it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it at least for the photo case using `UIImageWriteToSavePhotosAlbum` and yeah verily it was saved in the "Camera Roll" area.